# Swift - Display and connect multiple array values using table view controller

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, tableview

Could anyone help me understand why genesis chapters show up when I tapped other books, such as exodus and Leviticus.

I am trying to create a bible app utilizing tableviews and arrays.
You can take a look at the project through the link below.

https://github.com/nlplaw/EasyBible.git

Thank you.

Comment: We won't be going through the whole project to solve your issue. Hire a freelancer for it! If you want [so] to help you, focus on a particular problem. Share the code that's producing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you show the chapter view controller you don't send the information about what book has been selected in book view controller, you need to work that out.
2. For section 2 you don't have chapters - this will crash your app.